# Shiny modularized inputs inside pop-up modal aren't being written to reactiveValues when dismissed [flexdashboard/shinydashboard]

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard, shiny-reactivity

As a minimally-viable example, I [modularized](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) the basic example from here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html#simple_example

## Code snippet (copy-paste, run as `.Rmd` in RStudio should do the trick):

````
---
title: "stackoverflow example"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)  # install.packages("flexdashboard")
# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
library(datasets)
data(faithful)

# UI modules
sidebarCharts <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    p(),
    actionButton(ns("settings"), "Settings", icon = icon("cogs"), width = '100%', class = "btn btn-info"),p(),
    actionButton(ns("refreshMainChart") ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"), width = '100%', class = "btn btn-primary"),p()
    ,textOutput(ns("info"))  # FOR DEBUGGING
  )
}

mainChartUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("mainChart"), width = "100%")
}

# UI module for the 2 buttons in the modal:
modalFooterUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    modalButton("Cancel", icon("remove")),
    actionButton(ns("modalApply"), "Apply", icon = icon("check"))
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Init reactiveValues() to store values & debug info; https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1588
  rv <- reactiveValues(clicks = 0, applyClicks = 0,
                       bins = 20,
                       bandwidth = 1)

  # DEBUGGING
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste("You clicked the 'Settings' button", rv$clicks, "times. You clicked the 'Apply' button", rv$applyClicks, "times. The bin size is currently set to", rv$bins, "and the bandwidth is currently set to", rv$bandwidth)
  })

  settngsModal <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    modalDialog(
      withTags({  # UI elements for the modal go in here
        fluidRow(
          column(4, "Inputs",
                 selectInput(ns("n_breaks"), label = "Number of bins:", choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = rv$bins, width = '100%')),
          column(4, "Go",
                 sliderInput(ns("bw_adjust"), label = "Bandwidth adjustment:", min = 0.2, max = 2, value = rv$bandwidth, step = 0.2, width = '100%')),
          column(4, "Here")
        )
      }),
    title = "Settings",
    footer = modalFooterUI("inputs"), 
    size = "l",
    easyClose = FALSE,
    fade = TRUE)
  }

  # Sidebar 'Settings' modal
  observeEvent(input$settings, {
    showModal(settngsModal("inputs"))  # This opens the modal; settngsModal() defined below
    rv$clicks <- rv$clicks + 1  # FOR DEBUGGING
  })

  observeEvent(input$modalApply, {
    rv$applyClicks <- rv$applyClicks + 1  # FOR DEBUGGING
    rv$bins <- input$n_breaks  # This is where I set the reactiveValues() to those inputted into the modal.
    rv$bandwith <- input$bw_adjust
    removeModal()  # This should dismiss the modal (but it doesn't seem to work)
  })

  output$mainChart <- renderPlot({
    input$refreshMainChart  # Take dependency on the 'Refresh' buton

    hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(rv$bins),  
         xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser Eruption Duration")

    dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = rv$bandwidth)
    lines(dens, col = "blue")
  })

}

```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
callModule(server, "main")
sidebarCharts("main")
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Main chart goes here

```{r}
mainChartUI("main")
```
````

## Screenshots:

[image: Launch]
[image: Modal]

## This is the desired functionality:

1. On app launch, the chart should render with default parameters for bin-size and bandwidth stored in `rv` which is a `reactiveValues()` -- **this appears to work.**
2. When I click the modal, for the first time, it should appear with the default parameters for bin-size and bandwidth -- **this also appears to work.**
3. When I update either of the input parameters **AND** click 'Apply', it should dismiss the modal and subsequently set the respective parameters inside the `rv` `reactiveValues()` object to the one(s) selected -- **THIS DOES NOT WORK** (neither modal is dismissing, nor are `reactiveValues` being updated).
4. After the `reactiveValues()` inside `rv` are updated with the new ones, the chart should NOT re-render until user hits the 'Refresh' `actionButton` -- this also does not work, but is contingent on (3) above.

---

What am I doing wrong?? It feels like I'm overlooking something super simple.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that your modal and your server function have different `namespace` id's and so can't talk to each other in a normal way.

When you call your `server` function with `callModule`, you give your module the namespace id of `"main"`. When you generated your Modal, you gave it the namespace id of `"inputs"`.  So when you try to access the `actionButton` in your server with `observeEvent(input$modalApply...`, it doesn't work because it's looking for `modalApply` in the `inputs$` of its own namespace (`"main"`), which doesn't exist.

What you need to do is keep the modal in the same namespace as the server function that's calling it. You can do that by passing the `ns` function directly into the modal UI function from the session.

Instead of passing in an `id` and then re-generating ns with `ns <- NS(id)`, you can get the current sessions `ns` function directly with `session$ns` and then pass it into the UI functions for it to use:

```
observeEvent(input$settings, {
    showModal(settngsModal(session$ns))
}

...

settngsModal <- function(ns) {
    ...
    footer = modalFooterUI(ns), 
    ...
}
```

By passing `session$ns` in this way, you can ensure that the UI elements for the modal will always be in the same namespace as (and thus accessible to) the server function that calls it. You can read more about this here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html#using-renderui-within-modules

---

As for your second question, it's just a simple matter of wrapping the rest of the code in your `renderPlot` in an `isolate` function. The `isolate` function makes it so that changes in `reactive` values inside the `isolate` don't invalidate the expression and cause it to re-evaluate. Now, the only `reactive` value that can cause the `renderPlot` to re-evaluate is the one outside the `isolate`: `input$refreshMainChart`:

```
output$mainChart <- renderPlot({
    input$refreshMainChart  # Take dependency on the 'Refresh' buton
    isolate({
        hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(rv$bins),  
             xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser Eruption Duration")

        dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = rv$bandwidth)
        lines(dens, col = "blue")
    })
})
```

Comment: Ok, so I made the changes you mentioned in the first part; that is, I updated the argument to `settngsModal` to `settngsModal(session$ns)` for the call within `observeEvent` as well as the underlying function parameter itself, but now I get this error:

    Warning: Error in paste: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
      95: paste
      94: NS
      93: modalFooterUI [<text>#25]
      82: settingsModal [<text>#45]
  74: observeEventHandler [<text>#64]

Comment: Since you're passing the `ns` function directly, not an `id` string, you also have to get rid of the part where you call `ns <- NS(id)` and make sure that the argument is named `ns`, not `id`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I did remove the `ns <- NS(id)` from the first part of `settngsModal <- function(ns) {...}`. Am I also supposed to remove & alter this for `modalFooterUI` and `mainChartUI` ? Very confused still.

Comment: Yes, you need to change this for `modalFooterUI` too, since that's where your `modalApply` button is. When you call `modalFooterUI` in your `settngsModal` function, you should pass that same `ns` function into it so that the buttons in your modal footer still share the same namespace as your server

Comment: Light bulb just went on in my head after re-reading what you wrote and the link you provided in your original answer. Works great now. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Ray, could you post the full app with the correct code, I have a similar issue and I can't resolve it, thanks a lot