# How to display reactive UI for afvanced settings in modalDialog with Shinyusing moduals

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

I'm designing an app that will have multiple tabs that all have basic ui features on the side, but hid various advanced UI options in a pop-up modal button. Some of these options are responsive to the dataset, for example choosing which rows to use.

I want to use modules to design the app, but am running into trouble getting reactive UI elements into the modals.

I think modalUI1 is getting the right namespace, but when I call uiOutput on the reactive ui element made by settingsServer1 it doesn't show up.

The closest slack post I found did something similar, but the modal they had static UI.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042747/shiny-modularized-inputs-inside-pop-up-modal-arent-being-written-to-reactiveval)

```
# Basic View Functions ----------------------------------------------------
# These modules setup the basic view for each analysis

simpleui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  selectData <- selectInput(ns("d"), "Dataset:",
                    c("iris",
                      "mtcars",
                      "iris3"))
  outputRows <- verbatimTextOutput(ns("df"))
  settingsButton<-
    actionButton(
      ns("settings"),
      "Settings")
  tabPanel(id,
  tagList(
    p(),
    selectData,
    p(),
    outputRows,
    p(),
    settingsButton
  )
  )

}
view1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  reactiveDf <-  reactive({
    switch(input$d,
           "iris" = iris,
           "mtcars" = mtcars,
           "iris3"= iris3)
  })
  output$df <-  renderText({nrow(reactiveDf())})
  callModule(settingsServer1, "settings", reactiveDf)
  observeEvent(input$settings, {
    showModal(settngsModal(session$ns))
  })

  settngsModal <- function(ns) {
    # ns <- NS(id) ### This is inner UI so passed namespace from outer
    modalDialog(
      modalUI1("settings"), ### Call innerModalUI.
      # withTags({  # UI elements for the modal go in here
      #   fluidRow(
      #     column(4, "Inputs","Sectionnormal",uiOutput("nrowSlide")),
      #     column(4, "Inputs","Sectionnormal",uiOutput(ns("nrowSlide")))
      #   )}
      ,
      title = "Settings",
      footer = modalButton("Dismiss"),
      size = "l",
      easyClose = FALSE,
      fade = TRUE)
  }
}


# Advanced settings hidden in modal ---------------------------------------
# These functions should hide the advanced UI settings in a Modal.
modalUI1 <- function(ns) {
  ### Several UI elements 1 of which chooses which first N Rows.
  ### The slider is reactive
  # reactiveSlider <-  uiOutput("nrowSlide")
  withTags({  # UI elements for the modal go in here
    fluidRow(
      # print(ns("nrowSlide")),
      # print(input),
      column(4, "---------",uiOutput(("nrowSlide")), "---------")
    )
  })
}
settingsServer1 <- function(input, output, session, reactiveDf){
  output$nrowSlide <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                min = 1, max = nrow(reactiveDf()), value = 1)
  })
}



# Basic Setup -------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("My Application",
                         simpleui("v1"),
                         simpleui("v2")
))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(view1, "v1")
  callModule(view1, "v2")
  ### Also look for event to create a modal.
  ### This modal will have reactive items.



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you try `modalUI1(ns("settings"))` instead of `modalUI1("settings")` ? Alternatively, pass the `session` object to the modal function and use `session$ns` there.

Comment: The question was answered on the RStudio comminity site. [Here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-you-get-get-reactive-ui-elements-in-a-modal-with-modules/67898)